# Incorrect keystroke dwell/hold time if typed fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent, keystroke

**Aim**: Gather data(dwell time, flight time, down to down time...) for keystroke dynamics.

**Things accomplished**: Successfully obtained the flight time between two keystrokes.

**Problem**: When I type fast, I am able to obtain flight time correctly but dwell time messes up.

**Minimal, complete and verifiable example**: https://jsfiddle.net/nirajpandkar/600orotn/

For example for reproducing the error, you could try typing the word "the" slowly, one word at a time. The dwell times are as follows -

```
Pressed key 84 for 0.107

Pressed key 72 for 0.091

Pressed key 69 for 0.091
```

Now try typing letters 't' and 'h' in the word "the" as fast as you can(you won't have to try hard).  The dwell times are -

```
Pressed key 84 for 0.008

Pressed key 72 for 1490285526.868

Pressed key 69 for 0.074
```

**Question**: Why is this happening and how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that when typing fast it's possible for the `keydown` to fire *before* the previous `keyup`. Hence the `dwellTime` may not have been reset.

To alleviate the problem you could store the `dwellTime` on a per-keyCode basis so that it couples the `keydown` with the `keyup` for that given key, something like this:

```js
var dwellTimes = {};
$('#inputbox').keydown(function(e) {
  if (!dwellTimes[e.which])
    dwellTimes[e.which] = new Date().getTime();
});

$('#inputbox').keyup(function(e) {
  var dwellTime = new Date().getTime() - dwellTimes[e.which];
  delete dwellTimes[e.which];

  $('#output').prepend("<p>Pressed key " + e.which + " for " + dwellTime / 1000 + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputbox" type='text'>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Note that I used `prepend()` in this example so you don't have to scroll down to see the newly raised events. Also, I changed the logic so that if a key is held down the `dwellTime` accounts for that, as your previous logic did not. If you don't need that behaviour you can simply remove the `if` condition from the `keydown` event handler.

Comment: Ah that explains it! Appreciate the promptness :) Thanks!